# 2018 Community Moderator Election - Nomination Phase Extended

Tags: discussion, election

The [nomination phase of the moderator elections](https://android.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1) was scheduled to end today. However, we have insufficient candidates - for a 2 slot election, 3 candidates minimum is required. This ensures that the community is able to actually vote for candidates (avoiding default appointment) and also serves to help gauge community-wide interest in moderation. In order to find more willing volunteers, we will be extending the deadline for nominations for an additional seven days.

I've observed that there are individuals who have been considering running, but did not have the time to complete a nomination by today. Hopefully with this extension, they will be able to step up as desired. But don't let someone else planning to step up stop you from doing the same! Did you consider nominating but decided not to for some reason? Now would be a great time to reconsider!